# How to locate key to an SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, reverse-engineering

I'm using an Instant Messaging software, and I suspect that the software is retaing a lot of information about my machine (such as my MAC address) and possibly leaks it. I decided I want to check the local DBs of the software and see what it saves locally.

I have been able to locate, using the software's own log dump and Procmon, the interesting DBs. However, they are SQLite DBs that are key-protected.

1. Do I have any way to know what will be the format and size of the key? Will it be hex?
2. How can I efficiantly continue my research? I looked, using procmon, and been able to detect the first time that the software uses a key-protected DB from the first time it is being opened. However, I couldn't detect any 'interesting' local file that the software uses and could hint about the key's location - apart from several Windows Registries values that are being used - but I'm not so sure on how to approach that.

Sorry if I have mistakes in English, and thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Do I have any way to know what will be the format and size of the key? Will it be hex?

The key is just in plaintext (just like normal passwords) and the size is (also like passwords) defined by the creator of the database.

> 2. How can I efficiantly continue my research?

I would recommend reverse engineering the application and look for the part, where the connection to the database gets initiated. For that, you can use dynamic analysis (with a debugger) or static analysis (analyse the binary with a disassembler).